# Should I point my domain to Cloudflare?

Tags: web-hosting, dns, nameserver, cloudflare, best-practices

I have a couple of simple websites and my setup has always been like this:

1. Point my domain's registrar to my web hosting (via name servers)
2. Point my web hosting to my email provider (via DNS records)

Recently, I noticed that some people include Cloudflare as an intermediary. So from my limited understanding, their setup is then:

1. Point their domain's registrar to Cloudflare (via name servers)
2. Point Cloudflare to their web hosting and email provider (via DNS records)

What advantages and disadvantages does it entail?

I tried to look it up but googling something like *»cloudflare between registrar and hosting«* didn't help, unfortunately.

I also visited Cloudflare's website but there are so many services they offer that I quickly gave up trying to find an answer to this question there.

Comment: "What advantages and disadvantages does it entail? " This is too broad, and depends a lot on your constraints. Also CloudFlare provides many different services, for example they could handle "SSL certificates" for you, or not. Difficult to say if you should use it just in general. Also why CloudFlare and not any other CDN/DNS provider? There are many companies in the same market....

Comment: @Leo As Patrick pointed out, this is unfortunately too [broadly-scoped](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Questions seeking a list of advantages and disadvantages of third-party products don't fit the format of this site very well since they're difficult to vote on and accept as the "best" answer. In short, site owners use CloudFlare for security (both SSL and DDoS) protection and performance (speed improvements through quick DNS lookups and caching), but there are many more... I'd suggest starting with their free service and learning more as you go.